# Range filtering and splicing an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays that I'm filtering with a range slider. If the value of the specific selected parameter is within the user's set minimum (tMin) and max (tMax) values, it adds that to the new array (myNewArray) and reformats it in a way I need. Anything that is out of the range doesn't get added to this new array.  This part works perfectly fine.

The thing I can't seem to get working is I have a separate array (myOtherArray) which is formatted exactly the same as myArray, but instead of reformatting it I just need to remove the row if it doesn't fall within the range. myOtherArray should have the same values and number of rows as myNewArray, but they are both just formatted differently. What am I doing wrong here?

```
myArray.map(function (dataPoint, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        dataPoint.map(function (value, column) {
            // this first part works fine
            if ( dataPoint[paramToFilter] >= tMin && dataPoint[paramToFilter] <= tMax ) {  
                myNewArray[column] ? myNewArray[column].push(+value) : myNewArray[column] = [+value]  
            }
            // this is what I cannot get to work
            if ( dataPoint[paramToFilter] < tMin || dataPoint[paramToFilter] > tMax ) {  
                myOtherArray.splice(index, 1);
            }

        })
    }
})
```

thank you!!

Comment: Why are you using `Array.map` and not returning anything ?

Comment: Apparently he doesn't know about `Array.forEach`.

Comment: @Barmar - or that he can just return true or false to map out a new array instead of using push, splice and whatnot inside the loop ?

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with this. he doesn't need to use the return value, he's modifying other arrays.

Comment: @Barmar - well, yeah, `myNewArray`, I'm assuming that's a new array and that `var myNewArray = myArray.map( ... ` would be an option ?

Comment: The part of this code that worked originally - that some of you are commenting on - I did that way because it worked. I had no reason to do it another way. That being said, is there a significantly more efficient way to do the same exact thing? Efficiency/performance is key as this is going over thousands and thousands of rows and any number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the values of `myOtherArray` are not on the same index as in `myArray` once you called `myOtherArray.splice(index, 1)`.

Here is a small example showing the problem: http://jsbin.com/wipozu/1/edit?js,console

In order to avoid this problem you could simply "mark" those array items to be removed instead of removing it immediately. When you finished all checks (after `myArray.map(...)`) you could then remove all those "marked" items.

So instead of calling `myOtherArray.splice(index, 1);` you replace the item with `undefined` (or any other value) --> `myOtherArray[index] = undefined;`
And afterwards run the following for in order to remove all those `undefined` items.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myOtherArray.length; i++)
{
    if (myOtherArray[i] === undefined)
    {
        myOtherArray.splice(i, 1);
        // correct the index to start again on the same position because all
        // followings item has moved one index to the left in the array
        i--;
    }
}
```

The same example from before but using my solution: http://jsbin.com/wipozu/2/edit?js,console

So your code looks like this then:

```
myArray.map(function (dataPoint, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        dataPoint.map(function (value, column) {
            if ( dataPoint[paramToFilter] >= tMin && dataPoint[paramToFilter] <= tMax ) {  
                myNewArray[column] ? myNewArray[column].push(+value) : myNewArray[column] = [+value]  
            }

            if ( dataPoint[paramToFilter] < tMin || dataPoint[paramToFilter] > tMax ) {  
                myOtherArray[index] = undefined; // should be removed afterwards
            }

        })
    }
})

// remove all items that have been marked
for (var i = 0; i < myOtherArray.length; i++)
{
    if (myOtherArray[i] === undefined)
    {
        myOtherArray.splice(i, 1);
        // correct the index to start again on the same position because all
        // followings item has moved one index to the left in the array
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you splice out an element, the indexes of all the following elements shift down. As a result, the indexes in `myArray` and `myOtherArray` are no longer in sync, and when you later do `myOtherArray.splice(index, 1)` you remove the wrong element.

The simplest solution is to iterate from high to low instead of from low to high:

```
for (var index = myArray.length-1; index > 0; index--) {
    ...
}
```